# Efficiently write ReadOnlySequence to Stream

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, stream

Reading data using a `PipeReader` returns a `ReadResult` containing the requested data as a `ReadOnlySequence<byte>`. Currently I am using this (simplified) snippet to write the data fetched from the reader to my target stream:

```
var data = (await pipeReader.ReadAsync(cancellationToken)).Buffer;

// lots of parsing, advancing, etc.

var position = data.GetPosition(0);

while (data.TryGet(ref position, out var memory))
{
    await body.WriteAsync(memory);
}
```

This seems to be a lot of code for such a basic task, which I would usually expect to be a one-liner in .NET. Analyzing the overloads provided by `Stream` I fail to see how this functionality can be achieved with less code.

Is there some kind of extension method I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you are looking for is [planned for .NET 7:](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/58216)

> Stream wrappers for more types. Developers have asked for the ability to create a Stream around the contents of a ReadOnlyMemory, a **ReadOnlySequence**...

Not the greatest answer, but at least you can stop worrying that you are missing something obvious.